# Method(s) to Associate Text File with neo4j Node

Tags: neo4j

How would one associate a file with a node in neo4j?  For instance, I have ' Company ' nodes, which refer to companies that have issued investment securities.  I would like to link the node to the file that has a basic description of what that company offers for sale.  In other programs, I would add a hyperlink to the file.

The neo4j instance is running on a single computer as part of my personal workflow, so I do not need to concern myself with network connectivity or sharing w/ colleagues, etc. at this point.

Also, I reviewed two seemingly-related questions, including the one entitled Neo4J: Binary File storage and Text Search "stack", but neither seems to fit the bill.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can store a reference to the file as a property on the node. This can be either a URL or an id referencing the file in another database system (such as MongoDB).

Comment: Indeed, I may fall back on writing out the path name, but I was trying to avoid that method.  It seems a bit...inelegant.  I appreciate the suggestion, though.